# .htaccess mod-rewrite: RewriteRule Capturing values of {HTTP_HOST} AND {REQUEST_URI}

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect the following links

```
any-subdomain.domain-name.info/IGxxxx => https://www.mysite.de/link/ig/domain-name/xxx
any-subdomain.domain-name.info/IGxxxx/ => https://www.mysite.de/link/ig/domain-name/xxx
```

I tried the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:.+\.)?([^.]+)\.#/IG([^/]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/ig/%1/%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

...but i doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this ruke:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{REQUEST_URI} \.([^.]+)\.[^.#]+#/IG(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/ig/%1/%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

**Recommended solution:** There is no need to use compound variables here as we can capture value from `RewriteRule` pattern.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.([^.]+)\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^IG(.*)$ https://www.mysite.de/link/ig/%1/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! The first one does not work, the second one does. Any idea why (I am curious).

Comment: I found an issue with first rule and fixed it. We cannot match `$` in the middle of a regex. You can try now.

Comment: I still does not work. But I can work with the second one.

Comment: Weird because I have tested it on my Apache within a local subdomain it did work.

Comment: In any case it is recommended to use later solution. First one is only for academic purpose.